# Yii:: WARNING unable to include files on some pages; please explain

Tags: yii-extensions, yii

I have been recently running into this issue once I uploaded my Application to an online server,
I keep receiving Warnings such as:

```
YiiBase::include(CJuiInputWidget.php) [<a href='yiibase.include'>yiibase.include</a>]:       failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

--OR--

```
YiiBase::include(YiiMailer.php) [<a href='yiibase.include'>yiibase.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

--OR--

```
YiiBase::include(CGridColumn.php) [<a href='yiibase.include'>yiibase.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The real issue here is that all of these pages are working perfectly on my localhost or on other pages on
the online server.
When I hid the warnings, some pages are displayed normally while others are not, I know the error is still there.

My Localhost specs are:
XAMPP, Windows 7 OS, PHP Version 5.3.8

Online Server Specs:
XAMPP, Windows 7 OS, PHP Version 5.2.6

I am currently solving the issue by importing the required widgets in main.
What is also crazy for example is that CGridColumn and CJuiInputwidget are working perfectly on other pages  , 
I have made sure that case sensitivity is considered.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me any pointers or thoughts on what is happening, any tips or advices are amazingly appreciated!

Here is also a stack trace of whats going on:

```
**Stack trace:
 #0 D:\...\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(395): spl_autoload_call()
 #1 D:\...\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(395): autoload()
 #2 D:\...\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(296): autoload()
 #3 D:\...\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(196): import()
 #4 D:\...\yii\framework\zii\widgets\grid\CGridView.php(363):
```

createComponent()**

as you can see the major issue has to do with the autoload

Thank you, for taking the time to read this,

Comment: Could it be there's a case mismatch or spelling error on some pages?  Many/most unix-based servers require file name and declaration to be in the same case (so CJuiDatePicker is not the same as juidatepicker).

Comment: How do you render these widgets? For example, by default your app doesn't autoload CJuiInputWidget so you should specify full path to it in your view like that: <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CJuiInputWidget', array(...))?>

Comment: @ajsharma: The names are all absolutely the same, the pages run fine on my local XAMPP server, also the shared server is Windows Based.

Comment: @xapon: I basically render them in form using "$this->widget" where most widgets and extensions are imported automatically through main.
Please note that the exact same lines are used on other pages which work perfectly fine!

Comment: did you upload all the files to the remote machine, have you checked the file does excists ?

Comment: Yes as I have mentioned before the widgets are working perfectly on other pages.

Comment: Make sure that you have case sensitive files. If you are coming from Windows or Mac, both are not case-sensitive aware OS. While Shared servers are probably Linux, so they care about filename case sensitivity.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but as I have mentioned before, I am currently testing the app on my XAMPP/Windows localhost, to my surprise the online server is also XAMPP/Windows based. That's whats driving me crazy! **REMEMBER** Widgets are working perfectly on other pages!

Answer (score 1):

Could be the common problem of developing on windows, hosting on Linux. Windows doesn't care about the case of the filename, Linux does. I'd have a check through any widgets you've written or are including and any custom package definitions you have. Just ensure the case is correct.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but as I have mentioned before, I am currently testing the app on my XAMPP/Windows localhost, to my surprise the online server is also XAMPP/Windows based. That's exactly whats driving me crazy!

Comment: Damn. I think your next step is to try and isolate the problem. Figure out what's different about the pages where it works, and where it doesn't. If necessary create 2 test pages and try to recreate a working and non working page. This will give you a lot more to go on.

Comment: That's great advice! I will definitely try this out and let you know!

Comment: I created to absolutely new files using Gii, still the problem is not resolved, I keep receiving this:
--- YiiBase::include(CGridColumn.php) [<a href='yiibase.include'>yiibase.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory----

I think the problem has to do with configuring Yii path in Windows OS, where I just uploaded the files directly to the webserver.
Maybe the solution would be for them to do this instead 
[Yii Path](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/171/to-configure-yii-path-in-windows-platform/)

Comment: I have tried configuring yii from scratch, building a new webapp, still I receive the error, might it be a Permission/Access issue??
Please Help!!

Comment: Well I added this to the Index File ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);and the problem dissolved, still I can't comprehend what was happening!

Answer (score 0):

Well I added this to the Index.php in order to hide warnings...very dirty in my POV

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_NOTICE);
```

and the problem dissolved, still I can't comprehend what was happening!

Comment: Are you sure it's resolved completely? Changing the error reporting level would just mean the error is hidden. It still wouldn't be including the file correctly.

Comment: Well, it was a warning in general so I am not really sure how intensive it was and once I removed, the page ran smoothly in a way.
I still want to know why it was hapepening, and find another solution, this is just temporary.

Comment: So it was a warning about including a file? But it included the file anyway?